# Different Grub files to edit

Tags: grub2

I've been looking around to solve a black screen problem and found some pages with a very similar solution but each one using different grub files to edit.

For instance I've found examples using grub here `/etc/default/grub` and here `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

What is the difference between them and which one should I edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment at the start of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` says:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#
```

In other words, any time you run `update-grub` or it is run for you ( for instance, when install a new kernel, or certain other packages ), grub.cfg is thrown out and recreated, so edit /etc/default/grub.

Comment: Additionally colors in grub.cfg may require editing in `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ubuntu 9.10 karmic koala or later then it is Grub2. Grub2 uses `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and is generated automatically when you invoke `update-grub` command So you can not edit it.

you **MUST edit** `/etc/default/grub` or `/etc/grub.d/` but **Never edit** `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Answer (score 0):

/etc/default/grub is a user editable file which is used by update-grub and grub-mkconfig to construct /boot/grub/grub.cfg which is not usually edited by users.  Some experimenters and such edit it anyway knowing [or not] that their changes will be wiped out the next time update-grub is run.

There is another set of files in /etc/grub.d/ which are scripts used by grub-mkconfig in the process of making /boot/grub/grub.cfg.  This is another common place to work grub magic.

Answer (score 0):

The first, /etc/default/grub is the one you should edit. The second one, /boot/grub/grub.cfg, is produced by runing update-grub. There are comments in the beginning of each of those files reminding you of which is which. It mentions grub-mkconfig but that's a program that is run by update-grub.

The first one only has rather permanent information that tell update-grub what you want. The second merges that information with what operating systems you had on your system at the time you ran update-grub and is what grub itself uses to produce the boot menu.

To see information on using the /etc/default/grub use the `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'` command.

Most people don't have to mess with any of this. When Ubuntu is installed it puts something reasonable in /etc/default/grub and that is that.