# Code version control between local files and AU answers

Tags: bash, gui, yad

## Introduction

Note this is a self-answered question to “share knowledge”.

A “bash only” script is required to download Ask Ubuntu answers linked to source code (scripts) on my system. Then compare the two using the `diff` command.

The point is to discover if my code has been changed and AU answers need to be updated or has someone revised an AU answer I posted and I need to roll those changes into my code.

Comment: This should be posted on http://stackapps.com/

Comment: @muru I wish you were in AU General Chat Room the last 2 weeks where I was asking the best place to post this mega project *sigh*

Comment: I'm sure a few of the regulars know about Stack Apps - Nathan Osman has quite a few posts there, and most mods know about it.

Comment: I thought Terdon and Seth both knew this was coming... We were debating in AU or SO. Nathan was in room but his mind is in NitroShare. I'll setup an account there and check it out...Thanks :) PS all the data mining happens in AU, I just put SE in the question because AU is part of it so a broader audience would be interested.

Answer (score 4):

### `websync` script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: websync

# Must have the yad package.
command -v yad >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 \ 
  "yad package required but it is not installed.  Aborting."; \
  exit 99; }

RenumberListArr () {

IFS='|'

ListArrCnt=${#ListArr[@]}

i=1 # First array element (0) is "false", followed by record number element (1)
j=1 # All Record numbers count starting at 1

while [ $i -lt $ListArrCnt ] ; do
    ListArr[$i]=$j
    j=$(($j + 1))
    i=$(($i + $RecArrCnt))
done

} # RenumberListArr ()

ColSelect=0
ColRecNo=1
ColFileDate=2
ColFileName=3
ColStatus=4Address
ColAnsDate=5
ColA_Votes=5
ColWebAddr=6
ColQ_Votes=7
ColTitle=8

NewFileDate=0
NewFileName=1
NewStatus=2
NewAnsDate=3
NewA_Votes=3
NewWebAddr=4
NewQ_Votes=5
NewTitle=6

LineOut=""
HTMLtoText () {
    LineOut=$1  # Parm 1= Input line
    LineOut="${LineOut//&amp;/&}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&lt;/<}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&gt;/>}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&quot;/'"'}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&#39;/"'"}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&ldquo;/'"'}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&rdquo;/'"'}"
} # HTMLtoText ()


Ampersand=$'\046'
Equals="================================================================================="
Dashes="---------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
AnswerID=""
PercentFile="/tmp/websync-percent" # Temp file used for progress bar percentage

UpdateEntry () {

# PARM: 1=ONE display msgs, else file name for messages.

if [[ $1 == "ONE" ]] ; then
    bDisplayMsgs=true
    MsgFileName=""  # In case a single update follows all update
else
    bDisplayMsgs=false
    MsgFileName="$1"
fi

local BarNo="2"

# $RecArr[@] must be populated

# Searches in order they are found in an answer
SearchTitle=true
FoundTitle=false
SearchQ_Vote=true
FoundQ_Vote=false
SearchA_Vote=true
FoundA_Vote=false
FoundLine1=false
FoundLine2=false
FoundLine3=false
EndOfFile=false
AnswerWritten=false

AnswerID=$(echo ${RecArr[$ColWebAddr]} | rev | cut -d# -f1 | rev)

# Get file modified date in human readable format using STAT
RecArr[$ColFileDate]=$(stat "${RecArr[$ColFileName]}" | \
        grep "Modify:"| cut -f2 -d" ")

HoldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'       # make newlines the only separator

AnswerSize=$(stat -c%s "/tmp/$AnswerID")

# If answer size less < 1000 then wget failed.
if [[ $AnswerSize -lt 1000 ]] ; then
    yad --error --center \
    --text="wget failed to download answer from Stack Exchange."
    RecArr[$ColA_Status]="Answer < 1K"
    IFS="$HoldIFS"
    return 1
fi

FirstThreeLines=()

FirstThreeLines=( $(head -n10 ${RecArr[$ColFileName]}) )

AnswerLines=0
AllLinesSize=0
LastPercent=0
fPrintNextLine=false # Use this for tracing HTML and displaying Line

echo $BarNo:0 > "$PercentFile" # Just in case last time temp file wasn't removed

fEOFskip=false

while IFS= read -r Line; do

AnswerLines=$(( ++AnswerLines ))
AllLinesSize=$(( $AllLinesSize+${#Line} ))

if [[ $Line == *"$Ampersand""lt;/code$Ampersand""gt;"* ]] ; then
    # Answer contains </code> in text section, it's a fake End of Code tag.
    fEOFskip=true
else
    fEOFskip=false
fi

# Convert HTML codes to normal characters

HTMLtoText $Line
Line="$LineOut"

Percent=$(( $AllLinesSize * 100 / $AnswerSize ))
if [[ "$Percent" -ne "$LastPercent" ]] ; then
    LastPercent=$Percent
    # Send percentage via working file to spawned process with yad progress bar
    echo $BarNo:$Percent > "$PercentFile"
fi

if [ $fPrintNextLine = true ] ; then
    echo "Line at start: $Line"
fi

# Parse Line: </script> <dev id="question-header">

if [ $SearchTitle = true ] ; then
    if [[ $Line == *"<div id=\"question-header\">"* ]] ; then SearchTitle=false ; fi
    continue
fi

if [ $SearchTitle = false ] && [ $FoundTitle = false ] ; then
    if [[ $Line == *"<h1 itemprop=\"name\""* ]] ; then
        FoundTitle=true
        Title=$(cut -d ">" -f 3 <<< "$Line")
        Title=$(cut -d "<" -f 1 <<< "$Title")
        HTMLtoText $Title
        RecArr[$ColTitle]="$LineOut"
    fi
    continue
fi

if [ $SearchQ_Vote = true ] ; then
    if [[ $Line == *"<div class=\"question\""* ]] ; then SearchQ_Vote=false ; fi
    continue
fi

if [ $SearchQ_Vote = false ] && [ $FoundQ_Vote = false ] ; then
    if [[ $Line == *"<span itemprop=\"upvoteCount\""* ]] ; then
        FoundQ_Vote=true
        QuestionVotes=$(cut -d ">" -f 2 <<< "$Line")
        QuestionVotes=$(cut -d "<" -f 1 <<< "$QuestionVotes")
        RecArr[$ColQ_Votes]=$QuestionVotes
    fi
    continue
fi

# Parse lines: <a name="894470"></a>
# <div id="answer-894470" class="answer" data-answerid="894470"  itemscope
#  itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">

if [ $SearchA_Vote = true ] ; then
    if [[ $Line == *"<div id=\"answer-$AnswerID\""* ]]; then SearchA_Vote=false ; fi
    continue
fi

if [ $SearchA_Vote = false ] && [ $FoundA_Vote = false ] ; then
    if [[ $Line == *"span itemprop=\"upvoteCount\""* ]] ; then
        FoundA_Vote=true
        # We don't have array entries setup yet so store in working variable
        AnswerVotes=$(cut -d ">" -f 2 <<< "$Line")
        AnswerVotes=$(cut -d "<" -f 1 <<< "$AnswerVotes")
        RecArr[$ColA_Votes]=$AnswerVotes
    fi
    continue
fi

if [ $FoundLine1 = false ] ; then
    if [[ $Line == *"${FirstThreeLines[0]}"* ]] ; then # May have <code> prefix
        FoundLine1=true
        # Create file with first line taken from "clean" bash array
        echo "${FirstThreeLines[0]}" > /tmp/websync-webfile
    fi
    continue
fi

if [ $FoundLine1 = true ] && [ $FoundLine2 = false ]; then
    # Empty lines aren't in our array so skip test if in web file
    if [[ $Line == "" ]] ; then 
        echo "$Line" >> /tmp/websync-webfile # Append empty line
        continue
    fi
    if [[ $Line == "${FirstThreeLines[1]}" ]] ; then # Line 2 match exactly?
        FoundLine2=true
        echo "$Line" >> /tmp/websync-webfile # Append second line
    else
        # Line 2 doesn't match so force search to restart at line 1
        FoundLine1=false
    fi
    continue
fi

if [ $FoundLine2 = true ] && [ $FoundLine3 = false ]; then
    # Empty lines aren't in our array so skip test if in web file
    if [[ $Line == "" ]] ; then 
        echo "$Line" >> /tmp/websync-webfile # Append empty line
        continue
    fi
    if [[ $Line == "${FirstThreeLines[2]}" ]] ; then # Line 3 match exactly?
        FoundLine3=true
        echo "${FirstThreeLines[2]}" >> /tmp/websync-webfile # Append third line
    else
        # Line 3 doesn't match so force search to restart at line 1
        FoundLine1=false
        FoundLine2=false
    fi
    continue
fi

# We are only here when first three code lines have matched up in Stack Exchange.
if [ $EndOfFile = false ] ; then
    if [[ $Line == *"</code>"* ]] && [[ $fEOFskip == false ]] ; then
        EndOfFile=true
    else
        echo "$Line" >> /tmp/websync-webfile
    fi
fi

if [ $fPrintNextLine = true ] ; then
    echo "Line at end: $Line"
    fPrintNextLine=false
elif [[ $Line == *"---- ENTER SEARCH STRING HERE ----"* ]] ; then
    fPrintNextLine=true
fi

done < "/tmp/$AnswerID"

echo $BarNo:100 > "$PercentFile" # force spawned yad progress bar to close

if [[ ! -f "${RecArr[$ColFileName]}" ]] ; then   # File exists?
    yad --error --center --text "${RecArr[$ColFileName]} does not exist."
    RecArr[$ColStatus]="Bad File"
elif [[ ! -s "${RecArr[$ColFileName]}" ]] ; then  # File not empty?
    yad --error --center --text "${RecArr[$ColFileName]} is empty."
    RecArr[$ColStatus]="Empty File"
fi

if [ $FoundLine1 = true ] && [ $FoundLine2 = true ] && [ $FoundLine3 = true ]; then
    FileDiff="/tmp/websync-diff-"$(date +%s)
    if [[ "$MsgFileName" != "" ]] ; then
        echo $Equals >> $MsgFileName
    fi
    diff --unified=2 -w -b -B -I --suppress-blank-empty \
        --ignore-tab-expansion --suppress-common-lines --ignore-all-space \
        ${RecArr[$ColFileName]} /tmp/websync-webfile > $FileDiff

    # If file doesn't exist, errors in diff parameters
    # If file size =0 there were no differences
    if [[ -f $FileDiff ]] ; then
        if [[ -s $FileDiff ]] ; then
            if [[ $bDisplayMsgs == true ]] ; then
                # File not empty.
                gedit $FileDiff
            else
                cat $FileDiff >> $MsgFileName
            fi
            RecArr[$ColStatus]="Different"
        else
            if [[ $bDisplayMsgs == true ]] ; then
                yad --info --center --text \
                    "Code in ${RecArr[$ColFileName]} matches on Stack Exchange."
            else
                echo "Code in ${RecArr[$ColFileName]} matches on Stack Exchange." \
                     >> $MsgFileName
                echo $Dashes >> $MsgFileName
            fi
            RecArr[$ColStatus]="Matches"
        fi
    else
        yad --error --center --text "websync - Error in `diff` parameters."
        RecArr[$ColStatus]="Diff Parameter Error"
    fi
else
    if [[ $bDisplayMsgs == true ]] ; then
        yad --error --center --text \
        "First three lines of ${RecArr[$ColFileName]} not found on Stack Exchange."
    else
        echo $Equals >> $MsgFileName
        echo "First three lines of ${RecArr[$ColFileName]} not found on Stack Exchange." \
             >> $MsgFileName
        echo $Dashes >> $MsgFileName
    fi
    RecArr[$ColStatus]="3 lines not found"
fi

IFS="$HoldIFS"

# Remove Work files
rm "/tmp/$AnswerID"
rm /tmp/websync-webfile
rm "$PercentFile"
rm "$FileDiff"

return 0

} # UpdateEntry ()


UpdateOne () {

# $RecArr[@] must be populated

# $1= ONE or $MsgFileName
# $2= Bar 1
# Download stack exchange answer 
AnswerID=$(echo ${RecArr[$ColWebAddr]} | rev | cut -d# -f1 | rev) # Answer# for file name

local BarNo="1"
echo "$BarNo:10"    > "$PercentFile" # Zero percent complete
echo "$BarNo:#Downloading with wget." > "$PercentFile"

wget -O- "${RecArr[$ColWebAddr]}" > "/tmp/$AnswerID"
if [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]]               # check return code for errors
  then
    # Sometimes a second attempt is required. Not sure why.
    wget -O- "${RecArr[$ColWebAddr]}" > "/tmp/$AnswerID"
fi
if [[ "$?" == 0 ]]               # check return code for errors
  then
      echo "$BarNo:100" > "$PercentFile"
      echo "$BarNo:#Download completed." > "$PercentFile"
  else
      echo "$BarNo:100" > "$PercentFile"
      echo "$BarNo:#Download error." > "$PercentFile"
      echo "ERROR: $AnswerID" >> ~/websync.log
      return 1
fi

UpdateEntry $1
ret=$?
if [[ $ret != 0 ]] ; then
    # We weren't able to anayze SE answer -- too small
    return 1
fi

((TransCount++))            # Update count of changes

# Update array entry
let i=1
while [[ $i -lt $ListArrCnt ]] ; do
    if [[ ${ListArr[i]} == ${RecArr[1]} ]] ; then
        # We have matching record number
        ListArr[++i]="${RecArr[$ColFileDate]}"
        ListArr[++i]="${RecArr[$ColFileName]}" # File name should never change
        ListArr[++i]="${RecArr[$ColStatus]}"
        ListArr[++i]="${RecArr[$ColA_Votes]}"
        ListArr[++i]="${RecArr[$ColWebAddr]}"
        ListArr[++i]="${RecArr[$ColQ_Votes]}"
        ListArr[++i]="${RecArr[$ColTitle]}"
        let i=$(($ListArrCnt + 1)) # force exit from while loop
    else
        let i=$(($i + $RecArrCnt)) # Check next entry
    fi
done

return 0

} # UpdateOne ()


RecSelected=true # Overrides are below
UpdateAllOrOne () {

TITLE="websync"                             # dialog title
TEXT="<b>Update Entry</b> ${RecArr[$ColFileName]}"     # dialog text
ICON="emblem-downloads"                     # window icon (appears in launcher)
IMAGE="browser-download"                    # window image (appears in dialog)

# Process a single entry
if [[ $RecSelected == true ]] ; then

    echo "2:0" > "$PercentFile" # Just in case last time temp file wasn't removed

    # Repurpose yad progress bar as wget information message.
    CurrentEntry="${RecArr[$ColFileName]}"
    ( spawn-progress-multi $PercentFile \
        '--multi-progress --center --auto-close --skip-taskbar --title "websync" --text "Update Entry $CurrentEntry" --window-icon $ICON --image $IMAGE --fixed --width=600 --height=200 --watch-bar2 --bar=Downloading:NORM --bar=Analyzing:NORM' \
         2 & )

    UpdateOne ONE

    echo "2:100" > "$PercentFile" # Force progress display to shut down

    return $?
fi

MsgFileName="/tmp/websync-diff-"$(date +%s)
echo "--- /Prefix for files on local drive" > $MsgFileName
echo "+++ /Prefix for code in Stack Exchange answers" >> $MsgFileName

echo "3:0" > "$PercentFile" # Just in case last time temp file wasn't removed

# Repurpose yad progress bar as wget information message.
CurrentEntry="${RecArr[$ColFileName]}"
( spawn-progress-multi $PercentFile \
    "--multi-progress --center --auto-close --skip-taskbar --title "websync" --text `"`Update All Entries `"` --window-icon $ICON --image $IMAGE --fixed --width=1000 --height=200 --watch-bar3 --bar=Downloading:NORM --bar=Analyzing:NORM --bar=`"`Entry progress`"`:NORM" \
         3 & )

# Process all Entries
local let k=0
RecArr[0]=false
EndLoop=$(( ListArrCnt - 1 ))
while [ $k -lt $EndLoop ] ; do
    let i=k
    RecArr[$ColRecNo]="${ListArr[++i]}"
    RecArr[$ColFileDate]="${ListArr[++i]}"
    RecArr[$ColFileName]="${ListArr[++i]}"
    RecArr[$ColStatus]="${ListArr[++i]}"
    RecArr[$ColA_Votes]="${ListArr[++i]}"
    RecArr[$ColWebAddr]="${ListArr[++i]}"
    RecArr[$ColQ_Votes]="${ListArr[++i]}"
    RecArr[$ColTitle]="${ListArr[++i]}"

    echo "2:0" > "$PercentFile"
    echo "3:"$(( $k*100/$ListArrCnt )) > "$PercentFile"
    echo "3:#""${RecArr[$ColFileName]}" > "$PercentFile"

    UpdateOne "$MsgFileName"
    [[ "$?" != "0" ]] && return "$?" ; # clicked close on progress dialog or wget error

    let k=$(($k + $RecArrCnt)) # next entry
    if [ $k -ge $EndLoop ] ; then
        echo "3:100" > "$PercentFile"
    fi
done

# If file doesn't exist, errors in diff parameters
# If file size =0 there were no differences
if [[ -f $MsgFileName ]] && [[ -s $MsgFileName ]] ; then
    gedit $MsgFileName
fi

return 0

} # UpdateAllOrOne ()


ExternalSortArray () {

# Called on Save
cp --preserve ~/.websync ~/.websync~ #Make backup copy

IFS="|" read -ra ListArr < ~/.websync
ListArrCnt=${#ListArr[@]}
# echo "ListArrCnt: $ListArrCnt"

# Can't sort empty file or array with 1 entry
[[ $ListArrCnt -lt $(( $RecArrCnt + 1 )) ]] && return 0;

# Create Keys Index
echo " "
echo "1. Create Keys-Index Pairs File"
> ~/.websyncSort    # Empty existing file.

time for (( i=0; i<$ListArrCnt; i=i+$RecArrCnt )) ; do
    # Sort key = Question Title + Local File Name
    CurrKey="${ListArr[$(( $i + $ColTitle))]}${ListArr[$(( $i + $ColFileName))]//[^[:alnum:]\/]/}"
    echo "$CurrKey|$i" >> ~/.websyncSort
done

# Call external sort program
echo " "
echo "2. Sort Keys-Index Pairs File"
time sort -k1 -t"|" ~/.websyncSort -o ~/.websyncSort
# cat ~/.websyncSort

# Strip out keys
echo " "
echo "3. Strip out keys leaving Sorted Indices"
time cut -f2 -d '|' ~/.websyncSort > ~/.websyncNdx
# cat ~/.websyncNdx

echo " "
echo "4. Rewrite List Array by Sorted Index"
> ~/.websync    # Empty existing ListArr[] file.
RecNo=1         # Sequential record number

Second=""
time while read -r line; do 
    j=$(( $line + $RecArrCnt ))
    FldNdx=0
    for (( i=$line; i<j; i++ )); do
        LastChar="${ListArr[i]}"
        if [[ $FldNdx == $ColRecNo ]] ; then
            echo -n "$Second""$RecNo"    >> ~/.websync
            RecNo=$(( $RecNo + 1 ))
        else
            echo -n "$Second""$LastChar" >> ~/.websync
        fi
        Second="|"
        FldNdx=$(( $FldNdx + 1 ))

        # Update progress display
    done
done < ~/.websyncNdx

echo " "
printf "* * *  ExternalSortArray -- "
echo " Total elements: $ListArrCnt  * * *"

} ### ExternalSortArray ()

OldIFS="$IFS"
IFS="|"
ListArr=()

IFS="|" read -ra ListArr < ~/.websync

# Define variables for easy reading and fewer code line changes when expanding
RecArrCnt=9
ListArrCnt=${#ListArr[@]}

if [[ $ListArrCnt -lt $RecArrCnt ]] ; then
    # Handle empty file: Create dummy entries.
    ListArr+=("false" "1" "Update" "/boot/grub/grub.cfg" "Different" "Update")
    ListArr+=("http://askubuntu.com/questions/142293/different-grub-files-to-edit/142295#142295")
    ListArr+=("Update" "Dummy question.")
    ListArr+=("false" "2" "Update" "$HOME/.bashrc" "Different" "Update")
    ListArr+=("http://askubuntu.com/questions/820684/how-do-i-fix-the-terminal/820709#820709")
    ListArr+=("Update" "Dummy question.")
    ListArrCnt=${#ListArr[@]}
fi

TransCount=0 # Number of Inserts, Edits and Deletes

ButnView=10
ButnInsert=20
ButnEdit=30
ButnDelete=40
ButnUpdate=50
ButnCancel=60
ButnSave=80

while true ; do

if [[ $TransCount -eq 0 ]] ; then
    VariableCloseText="_Close"
else
    VariableCloseText="_Cancel ALL"
fi

# adjust width & height below for your screen 1600x800 default for 1920x1080 HD
# screen and adjust font="14" below if blue title text is too small or too large.

Record=(`yad --list --separator="|" --skip-taskbar \
    --title="websync - Compare code to answer posted on Stack Exchange." \
    --text="Click column heading to sort.\
    Select an entry before clicking: View / Insert / Edit / Delete / Update" \
    --width=1600 --height=800 --center --radiolist --grid-lines=both --no-markup \
    --button="_View":$ButnView     --button="_Insert before":$ButnInsert \
    --button="_Edit":$ButnEdit     --button="_Delete":$ButnDelete \
    --button="_Update":$ButnUpdate --button="$VariableCloseText":$ButnCancel \
    --button="_Save":$ButnSave \
    --search-column=3        --column "Select"       --column "Record Number":HD \
    --column "File Date":HD  --column "File Name":FL --column "Status" \
    --column "A+"            --column "Stack Exchange":HD \
    --column "Q+"            --column "Question Title" \
    "${ListArr[@]}"`)
Action=$?

RecSelected=false
RecArr=()
i=0

for Field in "${Record[@]}" ; do
    RecSelected=true
    RecArr[i++]=$Field
done

# Error checking
if [[ $Action == $ButnView ]] || [[ $Action == $ButnInsert ]] || [[ $Action == $ButnEdit ]] \
|| [[ $Action == $ButnDelete ]] ; then
    if [[ $RecSelected == false ]] ; then
    yad --error --text 'You must select a record before clicking: View / Insert / Edit / Delete.' --center
    continue
    fi
fi

# Insert before || or Edit ?
if [ $Action == $ButnInsert ] || [ $Action == $ButnEdit ] ; then

    # After changing file name or Stack Exchange Address these must be updated.
    RecArr[$ColFileDate]="Update"
    RecArr[$ColStatus]="Update"
    RecArr[$ColA_Votes]="Update"
    RecArr[$ColQ_Votes]="Update"
    RecArr[$ColTitle]="Update"
    # --text="Set fields and click OK to update" 
    # Note a space after \ generates invalid command error from yad
    NewRecArr=(`yad --form --width=900 --height=400 --center --skip-taskbar \
        --title="Select a file name and link it to Stack Exchange" \
        --text="Click OK to save. Click Cancel or press Escape to discard changes." \
        --field="File date":RO  --field="File name":FL  --field="Status":RO \
        --field="Answer +":RO   --field="Stack Exchange Address":TXT \
        --field="Question +":RO --field="Question Title":RO \
        ${RecArr[$ColFileDate]} ${RecArr[$ColFileName]} ${RecArr[$ColStatus]} \
        ${RecArr[$ColA_Votes]}  ${RecArr[$ColWebAddr]} \
        ${RecArr[$ColQ_Votes]}  ${RecArr[$ColTitle]}`)
    ret=$?

    # Cancel =252, OK = 0
    # OK & Insert operation?
    if [[ $ret == 0 ]] && [[ $Action == $ButnInsert ]]; then
        # Create new list entry and renumber
        ((TransCount++)) # Update number of changes
        let i=1      # Base 0 array, record number is second field

        while [ $i -lt $ListArrCnt ] ; do
            if [ ${ListArr[$i]} -eq ${RecArr[$ColRecNo]} ]; then
                # We have matching record number to insert before
                NewArr+=( false )               # Selected
                NewArr+=( "${RecArr[$ColRecNo]}" ) # Will be renumbered
                NewArr+=( "${NewRecArr[$NewFileDate]}" )
                NewArr+=( "${NewRecArr[$NewFileName]}" )
                NewArr+=( "${NewRecArr[$NewStatus]}" )
                NewArr+=( "${NewRecArr[$NewA_Votes]}" )
                NewArr+=( "${NewRecArr[$NewWebAddr]}" )
                NewArr+=( "${NewRecArr[$NewQ_Votes]}" )
                NewArr+=( "${NewRecArr[$NewTitle]}" )
            fi
            let j=$(( $i-1 ))
            let k=$(( $j+$RecArrCnt ))
            while [ $j -lt $k ] ; do
                NewArr+=( "${ListArr[$j]}" )
                j=$(($j + 1))
            done
            let i=$(($i + $RecArrCnt)) # Next list array entry to copy
        done
        ListArr=("${NewArr[@]}")
        unset NewArr
        RenumberListArr

    # OK & Edit operation?
    elif [[ $ret == 0 ]] && [[ $Action == $ButnEdit ]]; then
        # Update array entry
        ((TransCount++))
        let i=1
        while [ $i -lt $ListArrCnt ] ; do
            if [ ${ListArr[$i]} -eq ${RecArr[1]} ]; then
                # We have matching record number
                ListArr[++i]="${NewRecArr[$NewFileDate]}"
                ListArr[++i]="${NewRecArr[$NewFileName]}"
                ListArr[++i]="${NewRecArr[$NewStatus]}"
                ListArr[++i]="${NewRecArr[$NewA_Votes]}"
                ListArr[++i]="${NewRecArr[$NewWebAddr]}"
                ListArr[++i]="${NewRecArr[$NewQ_Votes]}"
                ListArr[++i]="${NewRecArr[$NewTitle]}"
                let i=$(($ListArrCnt + 1)) # force exit from while loop
            else
                let i=$(($i + $RecArrCnt)) # Check next entry
            fi
        done
    else
        : # noop for readibility: Cancel or Escape pressed in Insert / Edit window
    fi

# View or Delete record?
elif [[ $Action == $ButnView ]] || [[ $Action == $ButnDelete ]] ; then

    # Note if there is a space after "\", the next line generates
    # "invalid command" error message from yad.
    if [[ $Action == $ButnDelete ]] ; then
        YadTitle="Do you really want to delete this entry?"
        YadText="Click OK to confirm delete."
    else
        YadTitle="websync - Single entry view mode"
        YadText="Click any button or press Escape after viewing entry."
    fi

    yad --width=900 --height=600 --form --center --skip-taskbar \
        --title="$YadTitle"      --text="$YadText" \
        --field="File date":RO   --field="File name":TXT --field="Status":RO \
        --field="Answer +":RO    --field="Stack Exchange Address":TXT \
        --field="Question +":RO  --field="Question Title":TXT \
        ${RecArr[$ColFileDate]} ${RecArr[$ColFileName]} ${RecArr[$ColStatus]} \
        ${RecArr[$ColA_Votes]}  ${RecArr[$ColWebAddr]}  ${RecArr[$ColQ_Votes]} \
        ${RecArr[$ColTitle]}
    ret=$?

    if [[ $Action == $ButnView ]] ; then
        continue
    fi

    # Cancel =252, OK = 0
    if [[ $ret == 0 ]] && [[ $Action == $ButnDelete ]] ; then
        # Delete record from list array and renumber
        ((TransCount++))
        let i=1
        while [ $i -lt $ListArrCnt ] ; do
            if [ ${ListArr[$i]} -eq ${RecArr[$ColRecNo]} ]; then
                # We have matching record number to delete
                j=$(($i - 1))
                k=$(($j + $RecArrCnt))
                while [ $j -lt $k ] ; do
                    unset 'ListArr[$j]'
                    j=$(($j + 1))
                done
                for i in "${!ListArr[@]}"; do
                    NewArr+=( "${ListArr[$i]}" )
                done
                ListArr=("${NewArr[@]}")
                unset NewArr
                let i=$(($ListArrCnt + 1)) # force exit from while loop
            else
                let i=$(($i + $RecArrCnt)) # Check next entry
            fi
        done
        RenumberListArr
    else
        : # cancel delete operation.
    fi

# Run update process?
elif [[ $Action == $ButnUpdate ]] ; then
    time UpdateAllOrOne
    ret=$?

# Cancel all changes or "252"= X the window or Escape?
elif [[ $Action == $ButnCancel ]] || [[ $Action == 252 ]] ; then
    if [[ $TransCount -gt 0 ]] ; then
        (`yad --image "dialog-question" --title "websync - Exit confirmation." \
        --text="You have made $TransCount change(s). Do you really want to exit?" \
        --button=_Stay:1 --button=_Exit:2 --center`)

        if [[ $? -eq 2 ]] ; then
            exit
        fi
    else
        exit
    fi

# Save changes?
elif [[ $Action == $ButnSave ]] ; then
    # Save
    echo "${ListArr[*]}" > ~/.websync # Using * instead of @ preserves |
    ExternalSortArray
    exit
else
    yad --error --center --text "websync - Unknown button return code: $Action"
    exit
fi

done

IFS="$OldIFS"

exit
```

### `spawn-progress-multi` script

***If you don't put `spawn-progress-multi` file in your path websync will not be able to run it***

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: spawn-progress-multi

Percent=0

MYNAME=$0
/usr/bin/logger $MYNAME "multi-progress FIFO named pipe: $1"
val="$2"
/usr/bin/logger $MYNAME "multi-progress yad parameters: $2"
/usr/bin/logger $MYNAME "multi-progress bar number to watch: $3"

while true ; do # loop until 100 %

    # Percent=$(cat "$1")
    [[ -f "$1" ]] && read -r Percent < "$1"
    echo "$Percent"
    if [[ $Percent == *"$3:100"* ]] ; then break ; fi ;

done | yad $2

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

This solution is divided into multiple answers due to the 32KB size limitation for Ask Ubuntu (AU) answers.

This first section provides the user guide with screen shots and field explanations.

The next section provides the bash scripts that gets the job done.

## Overview

All Ask Ubuntu (AU) answers are stored in HTML (Hypertext Markup Language) format. There is a high degree of confidence this application will work on all Stack Exchange (SE) sites but it has only been tested with AU.

The application will:

- Extract question title
- Extract question upvotes
- Extract answer upvotes
- Extract SE code matching first three lines of linked file name containing code
- Run `diff` command between SE code and local code displaying results in `gedit`.
- Display progress bars
- Easy to use GUI with no terminal requirements
- No installation other than copying bash script
- Comes with sample data to existing files on disk (Ubuntu 16.04) and existing answers.

## Sample Main Window

[image: websync main.gif]

This demo screen had to be fast paced and frame reduced to fit within 2MB file limit. It shows the default data created when the script is first run. Here’s what’s happening:

- Select the second entry
- Click on the `Update` button
- `wget` downloads the question and answer from Stack Exchange a progress bar is briefly diplayed.
- The question and answer are analyzed and a progress bar is displayed for about 3 seconds.
- The `diff` command compared the local code `~/.bashrc` to the answer on Stack Exchange and `gedit` was used to display the differences.

Here’s what was missed after the animation ended:

[image: websync gedit.png]

`gedit` is used to display the differences between your local code `~/.bashrc` and the stack exchange answer.

[image: websync main 2.png]

After closing `gedit` the main screen reappears and now the Question up-votes, Answer up-votes and Question title fields are populated.

Let’s drill down by clicking the `View` button

[image: websync view button]

Here you can see all the fields for an entry that don’t fit on the main screen. You can copy to the clipbaord the stack exchange website address which you could then paste into your browser. You can see the last modified date of the code file stored on your system.

The **Status** field could contain:

- `Update` - A new entry was added or an existing entry was changed. The Update button must be clicked to clear all fields tagged as update and set with real values from Stack Exchange.
- `Bad file` - The file name specified no longer exists.
- `Empty file` - The file name specified has zero bytes.
- `3 lines not found` - The first three lines of the specified file (blank lines are skipped) were not found in the Stack Exchange answer. Either the wrong file name was entered or the wrong Stack Exchange answer was provided or the files have been changed such that the first three lines no longer match.
- `Bad Answer` - The website address does not exist.
- `Answer < 1K` - The website address exists but the answer is less than 1 KB in size.
- `Different` - The local code file and the Stack Exchange Answer have differences.
- `Matches` -  The local code file matches the Stack Exchange Answer answer.
- `Diff parameter Error` -  The parameters used to call the `diff` command contain one or more errors. Use `man diff` to review valid options.

## Project Scope

The primary purpose is to find out which answers have been modified by others and to roll those changes into local code files. The other purpose is to figure out which answers in Stack Exchange need to be updated after coding changing have occurred locally. Lastly “hot” answers can be tracked with tallies of answer votes.

No SQL database should be used. Only out-of-the-box-bash files must be used. The application must use `yad` as the GUI user interface. `Zenity` is too limited as it cannot display original values in forms, cannot hide columns when database is too wide and does not allow adding buttons to control program flow.

Explaining the sample main window shown above it displays scrollable entries containing:

- Radio button to select an entry
- The local file name containing code
- Answer Up-votes (which your posted code and written answer are garnering)
- Question Up-Votes (to show global interest in this SE question)
- Question Title

A summary of main window buttons are:

- `View` - view the selected entry.
- `Insert before` - insert a new entry before the selected entry.
- `Edit` - edit the selected entry.
- `Delete` - delete the select entry (confirmation is required).
- `Update` - download the answer from Stack Exchange and analyze it.
- `Cancel ALL` - Cancel all changes (confirmation required if changes have been made). Escape key or X on Window has same effect.
- `Save` - Save changes to disk.

The `View` and `Delete` buttons pop up a the same window as shown above.

The `Insert before` and `Edit` buttons pop up similar window but some fields are non-input and initialized with “Update”. This indicates the `Update` button on the main window needs to be clicked to retrieve data from Stack Exchange later. The non-input fields are: File Date, Status, Answer Up-votes, Question Up-votes and Title.

---

## June 2017 Updates

The code has been revised to sort array entries by Question Title + local file name when changes are saved. There is no longer any need to manually insert records in sequential order.

You can now `update all` by clicking the `update` button without selecting a specific records. When updating all file comparisons are rolled into a single file and presented by `gedit` when complete. Answers with identical source code are not presented in dialog boxes interrupting the flow but put as status lines in the `diff` file.

Accelerator keys are provided for buttons. Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then tap the first letter of the button you want to select.

`sed` was taking 3 seconds to change HTML to text which was too long. It was replaced with built in `bash` search & replace and time is now one second or less.

Unfortunately these code changes are 2,000 characters too long for **Ask Ubuntu** posting so please leave a comment if you would like a copy of the code and I'll find some place to post it for you.