# How can I find my Internet Service Provider (ISP) using a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to use my Internet Service Provider's name in a script, and I don't know how can I do this.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use many websites provided to find your ISP name. One of them is [whoismyisp](https://www.whoismyisp.org/).

To get your ISP name in a bash script, you can get this site by something like `curl.`

```
header='--header=User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11'
wget "$header" -q -O - whoismyisp.org | grep -oP -m1 '(?<=block text-4xl\">).*(?=</span)'
```

Also you can find ISP of any desired IPs with this command:

```
header='--header=User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11'
wget "$header" -q -O - whoismyisp.org/ip/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx | grep -oP -m1 '(?<=block text-4xl\">).*(?=</span)'
```

Where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is that IP you want to find its ISP.

---

**Additional information**: You can find your IP by bash with this command (that may be helpful for scripts):

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

Comment: @TaraSVolpe I'm glad I could help you

Comment: This answer relies on the layout of this website, while ipinfo.io uses a well-defined JSON format. I don't understand why this answer is more upvoted.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Maybe because ipinfo.io/org only give the AS number but not the name of the ISP

Comment: @SebMa When I ran Byte's answer on my machine in Ubuntu in Windows 10 (WSL) it returned the AS number plus the ISP name using `curl ipinfo.io/org`. None-the-less I up-voted both answers and the question because it's all good :)

Comment: @NieDzejkob `curl ipinfo.io/org` does not output the full name of the AS but `curl -s ipinfo.io/ASxxx | grep as-name` does :)

Answer (score 41):

You could use e.g. the services of [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/) to determine your public IP including some additional information like the provider company name.

The site can be normally visited in your browser, but if you query it from the command-line with e.g. `curl`, they respond in a clean and well-defined JSON format so that you don't need to parse any HTML:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io
{
  "ip": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  "hostname": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx",
  "city": "xxxxxxxx",
  "region": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "country": "xx",
  "loc": "xxx.xxxx,xxx.xxxx",
  "org": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "postal": "xxxxx"
}
```

To only show one value, you can directly send a request to the respective path. E.g. for the ISP name (`org`), try this:

```
curl ipinfo.io/org
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/95911/367990).

Comment: Yes, ipinfo is better than whoismyisp because of its JSON format +1

Comment: @AliRazmdideh Very magnanimous indeed that you upvote the other guys answer :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks, I think it's better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

First I fetch the Autonomous System number :

```
$ curl -s ipinfo.io/org
AS2094 Renater
```

Then I fetch the full name of that AS :

<s>$ curl -s ipinfo.io/$(curl -s ipinfo.io/org | cut -d" " -f1) | awk '/as-name/{print$NF}'</s>

```
$ whois $(curl -s ipinfo.io/org | cut -d" " -f1) | awk -F: 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/(as-?name|org-?name):/{sub("^  *","",$2);print$2}'
FR-TELECOM-MANAGEMENT-SUDPARIS
Renater
```

Comment: For me it's not working. I just tested all answers in both Ubuntu in Windows 10 (WSL) and Ubuntu 16.04 with Kernel 4.14.27. Your option 1 above (Byte's answer) returns  `AS852 TELUS Communications Inc.`. Your option 2 above returns nothing. The accepted answer uses `curl -s https://www.whoismyisp.org | grep -oP '\bisp">\K[^<]+'` and returns `Telus Communications` which is a limited version of Byte's answer but still good. This is one of those **YMMV** (Your Mileage May Vary) answers.

Comment: Apparently it depends on the provider or on what `ipinfo.org` has in their data collection. For me `curl -s ipinfo.io/org` gives `AS3320 Deutsche Telekom AG` while `curl -s ipinfo.io/AS3320 | grep as-name` gives `DTAG` (after a while). Also, the latter is again parsing HTML output (error-prone!). So I'll stick with ByteCommander's answer.

Comment: @PerlDuck When I use Germany's `AS3320` I get the same `DTAG` output you get. But I wonder if you use Canada's `curl -s ipinfo.io/AS852 | grep as-name` you get null output like me.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes, same for me. No output. I reckon `curl -s ipinfo.io/org` returns data based on the requesting IP while `curl -s ipinfo.io/AS3320` returns data based on the given parameter (ignoring the request's IP). Anyway. Parsing HTML without a proper parser is almost always a bad idea. Do you know this [famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5830574) on [SO]? It's fun to read.

Comment: @PerlDuck It is a fun read especially all the weird characters at the end. Throwing caution to the wind I did parse HTML code in bash: https://askubuntu.com/questions/900319/code-version-control-between-local-files-and-au-answers/900609#900609

Comment: @PerlDuck Hi, I've updated my answer so has to parse ASCII output instead of HTML output

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Hi, I've updated my answer so has to parse ASCII output instead of HTML output

Answer (score 1):

I actually really like to use *api.bgpview.io* and *ifconfig.me*:
A bash one-liner (requires `apt install curl jq`) is:

```
curl -L -s "https://api.bgpview.io/ip/$(curl -s ifconfig.me)" | jq -r '.data.prefixes | .[] | (.prefix | tostring) + " " + (.ip | tostring) + " " + (.asn.asn | tostring) + " " + .asn.name + " " + .asn.description'
```