# Is it possible to get text from a website in terminal

Tags: bash, scripts

I would like to get a timetable from my schools website and use it in a script to set automatic alerts but I don't know how.

So it seems my school uses [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) to set the timetable so the times aren't HTML tags in the .html file.

Comment: What text? What website? It is very possible, but we can't help you parse data you don't show. Please [edit] your question and give us an example website and the text you want to extract from it.

Comment: Might be related: [Data scraping with wget and regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361229/data-scraping-with-wget-and-regex), I suggest using python for this purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we don't have the real website you want to scrape data from, and website scraping is always different if you don't have some standardized API, it's not possible to give a 100% working solution. But I'll try to explain a way to get to your information.

`fullcalender.io` is Javascript based, the events are set up as Javascript object or may be imported from `json` format. If the latter is the case, you can easily just download the ready `json` file that is referred to somewhere in the Javascript source code. Regarding parsing `json`, there are many Questions and Answers around here.

If it's set up as a Javascript Object, you can just parse the `.js` file or if it's included in a html `<script>` tag, parse the html for the `$('#calendar').fullCalendar(` object.

We can use `curl` to get the website, then extract the information using e.g. `awk`.

---

I made a small script to get the object for the `fullcalender.io` [*Basic View* demo](https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/demos/basic-views.html). Your script may look similar.

```bsh
curl -s https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/demos/basic-views.html \
  | awk '/\.fullCalendar\(\{/{s=1; print "{"; next;};
         /\}\)\;/{s=0};
         s{print};
         END{print "}";}'
```

**Explanation:**

- `/\.fullCalendar\(\{/{s=1; print "{"; next;};` Searches `.fullCalender({` and if found sets variable `s=1` and prints `{`
- `/\}\)\;/{s=0};` Searches for `)};` and sets variable `s=0`
- `s{print};` prints the line if `s` is set and not 0.
- `END{print "}";}'` prints the `}` at the end.

**Output:**

```
{
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
  },
  defaultDate: '2018-03-12',
  navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  events: [
    {
      title: 'All Day Event',
      start: '2018-03-01'
    },
    {
      title: 'Long Event',
      start: '2018-03-07',
      end: '2018-03-10'
    },
    {
      id: 999,
      title: 'Repeating Event',
      start: '2018-03-09T16:00:00'
    },
    {
      id: 999,
      title: 'Repeating Event',
      start: '2018-03-16T16:00:00'
    },
    {
      title: 'Conference',
      start: '2018-03-11',
      end: '2018-03-13'
    },
    {
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: '2018-03-12T10:30:00',
      end: '2018-03-12T12:30:00'
    },
    {
      title: 'Lunch',
      start: '2018-03-12T12:00:00'
    },
    {
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: '2018-03-12T14:30:00'
    },
    {
      title: 'Happy Hour',
      start: '2018-03-12T17:30:00'
    },
    {
      title: 'Dinner',
      start: '2018-03-12T20:00:00'
    },
    {
      title: 'Birthday Party',
      start: '2018-03-13T07:00:00'
    },
    {
      title: 'Click for Google',
      url: 'http://google.com/',
      start: '2018-03-28'
    }
  ]
}
```

You can then parse the JS object to a JSON object using python and `demjson`:

Install `demjson`:

```
pip3 install demjson
```

and then run this:

```bsh
curl -s https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/demos/basic-views.html \
  | awk '/\.fullCalendar\(\{/{s=1; print "{"; next;};
         /\}\)\;/{s=0};
         s{print};
         END{print "}";}' \
  | python3 -c "import demjson, sys, json; print(json.dumps(demjson.decode('\n'.join(sys.stdin.readlines()))));" \
  | jq ".events"
```

From here it should be fairly easy to move on using `jq`. Of course instead of `bash` and `jq` you can do the whole thing in `Python`.

Comment: I think I only need the events. What is the awk script for just the events?

Comment: I added a way to convert the JS object to a JSON string using python, which you can then parse with `jq` which should be the preferred tool to parse `json`. Don't use `awk` for that ... It will only cause pain ...

Answer (score 0):

The [websync](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900319/code-version-control-between-local-files-and-au-answers/900609#900609) bash script uses `wget` to retrieve answers here in **Ask Ubuntu**. It searches HTML tags to find Question Upvotes and Answer Upvotes. It converts special HTML symbols such as `&amp` to `&` and `&lt` to `<`, etc.

Here are a few snippets from the code you may find helpful:

```bash
LineOut=""
HTMLtoText () {
    LineOut=$1  # Parm 1= Input line
    LineOut="${LineOut//&amp;/&}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&lt;/<}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&gt;/>}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&quot;/'"'}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&#39;/"'"}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&ldquo;/'"'}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&rdquo;/'"'}"
} # HTMLtoText ()

Ampersand=$'\046'

(... SNIP LINES ...)

while IFS= read -r Line; do

(... SNIP LINES ...)

# Convert HTML codes to normal characters
HTMLtoText $Line
Line="$LineOut"

(... SNIP LINES ...)

done < "/tmp/$AnswerID"

(... SNIP LINES ...)

wget -O- "${RecArr[$ColWebAddr]}" > "/tmp/$AnswerID"
if [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]]               # check return code for errors
  then
    # Sometimes a second attempt is required. Not sure why.
    wget -O- "${RecArr[$ColWebAddr]}" > "/tmp/$AnswerID"
fi
if [[ "$?" == 0 ]]               # check return code for errors
  then
      echo "$BarNo:100" > "$PercentFile"
      echo "$BarNo:#Download completed." > "$PercentFile"
  else
      echo "$BarNo:100" > "$PercentFile"
      echo "$BarNo:#Download error." > "$PercentFile"
      echo "ERROR: $AnswerID" >> ~/websync.log
      return 1
fi
```